# Bash Group command not found

Tags: command-line, bash

I am new to Ubuntu and I am facing a problem. Whenever I launch a new terminal instance I get this error:

[image]

```
bash: groups: command not found
```

[OUTPUT for command- bash -i -x < /dev/null](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23580386/)

Comment: in a new terminal: `mv .bashrc{,.bak} && cp /etc/skel/.bashrc .bashrc && . .bashrc`

Comment: Didnt work !! I opened a new terminal instance and as it is copied the command  but still getting the same error .

Comment: hmm interesting... the command `groups` should be found anyway... did you do something that might have caused this?

Comment: @Zanna was having some Grub issues and solved it only to see this error. Pre Grub error it was working perfectly fine. Also I am not able update my grub it shows "/usr/sbin/update-grub: line 34: tr: command not found
"

Comment: What procedure did you use to solve your GRUB problem? It sounds like you may have some PATH issues

Comment: @Zanna  Initially I got an error (Unknown file system grub rescue)  then made a live usb (bootable Ubuntu 14.04 ) opened terminal and did " sudo update-grub" and restarted my laptop . Grub issue was solved but since then i am facing this problem also i am not able to execute any of my .sh files (Android studio etc). I also feel that their might be some PATH issues. Do you need any screenshots or something?

Comment: hmm it seems very strange that all this could be caused just by running `update-grub` (but you had to `chroot` into your installation to do that, I presume?) You should run the command suggested by David Foerster and post the output to see if we can debug your shell issues... Your initial GRUB problem suggests a possible hardware problem, but really, I'm not sure about anything...

Comment: @Zanna yea totally confused . I will post the output file as suggested by David Foerster

Comment: @Zanna  https://paste.ubuntu.com/23580386/

Comment: @DavidFoerster i have posted the link in the question (output). For the command ls -l /usr/bin/groups ( output- ls: cannot access /usr/bin/groups: No such file or directory ) and for the other command output -https://paste.ubuntu.com/23580386/

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the `groups` program was deleted on your system as indicated by the output of `ls /usr/bin/groups`. The best way to restore it is to reinstall the corresponding package.

To find the package:

```
$ dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/groups
coreutils: /usr/bin/groups
```

To restore the corrupted package:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```